# Objective-C, Refresh navigationBar in viewWillAppear

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem, popviewcontrolleranimated

For some reason, when I use `popViewControllerAnimated` to return to a previous view, the tint of the `UIBarButtonItem` turns grey, rather than the desired purple color (which is set in the storyboard).

Is there a way to refresh the navigationBar within the `viewWillAppear` method?  I've tried using `[self.navigationController loadView];`, but that causes other issues and prevents the view from loading.

Answer (score 0):

You could change it back programmatically.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear
{
UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
myNavController.navigationBar.tintColor = color;
}
```

Use http://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/RGB_Color.htm to find a color.

Comment: No dice.  Tried `UIColor *color = [UIColor purpleColor];
    UINavigationController *myNavController = self.navigationController;
    myNavController.navigationBar.tintColor = color;` and nothing changed.

Comment: In the `viewWillApear` method?

Comment: Yes.  I have a few other settings (initializations) that I handle in the same method.  None that deal with appearance, and none that interfere with the tint.  This is something else...

Comment: Please see my code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24470951/objective-c-button-tint-changes-color-when-using-popviewcontrolleranimated).  I posted this question as a follow-up to the question in the link, because I had solved one of the two issues in that particular thread.

Comment: Got it!  Please see **Edit #2** in **[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24470951/objective-c-button-tint-changes-color-when-using-popviewcontrolleranimated)** thread for the solution.  The problem stemmed from calling the `popViewControllerAnimated` before the view had finished loading.